# VueJS pagination doesnt change data

Tags: vue.js

I have array of data and trying to make pagination with that data. The problem is that when I click next page the data doesnt change on screen but I get required data in console.log

This is the component:

Data:

```
data: () => {
    return {
        invites: [] // Data array
        size: 2
    }
},
```

Method to change data:

```
methods: {
    currentPage(pageNum) {
        const start = pageNum * this.size;
        const end = start + this.size;

         this.invites.slice(start, end).reverse();
    }
},
```

Now when I do `console.log(this.invites.slice(start, end).reverse())` I get the data from array which should be displayed on screen. And this is the `v-for` loop:

```
<li v-for="invite in invites.slice(0, 2).reverse()" :key="invite.id">
```

It shows me first two results but it doesnt change when I trigger the method to change data

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), it has a return value. In your `currentPage` method assign the return value to the `invites` data property.

`this.invites = this.invites.slice(start, end).reverse();`

Answer (score -1):

You can set by this way too:

```
this.$set(this, 'invites', this.invites.slice(start, end).reverse());
```